# Parse text using regular expressions

Tags: regex, parsing

I have a dictionary in .txt format, which looks like this:

```
term 1
    definition 1
    definition 2

term 2
    definition 1
    definition 2
    definition 3
etc.
```

There is a tab always before a definition, basically it's like this:

```
term 1
[tab]definition 1
[tab]definition 2
etc.
```

Now I need to wrap every term and it's definitions with `<term>` tag, i.e:

```
<term>
term 1
    definition 1
    definition 2
</term>
```

I was trying to use regular expressions to find term with it's definitions, but with no luck. Could you please help me with this?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: What language/regular expression implementation do you use?

Comment: Please don't tell me you're trying to generate valid xml with regular expressions.

Comment: @Anon.: What’s wrong with using the help of regular expressions to generate an XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
(^|\n).+(\n[ \t]+.+)*
```

Assuming that `^` marks the start of the string, `\n` is the line break character and `.` does not match line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an implementation that

1. Matches multiple lines (`/.../m`)
2. Uses `\A` to indicate the start of a line

this should match one "term":

```
\A[^\t][^\n]+\n(\t[^\n]+\n)+
```

Answer (score 0):

Match a line with a leading non-whitespace character followed by one or more lines with leading TABs:

```
$ perl -0077 -pe 's/^(\S.+\n(^\t.+\n)+)/<term>\n$1<\/term>\n/mg' dict
<term>
term 1
        definition 1
        definition 2
</term>

<term>
term 2
        definition 1
        definition 2
        definition 3
</term>
```